# HiveQL equivalent of MySQL's TRUNCATE()?

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

What is the HiveQL equivalent of MySQL's `TRUNCATE()`?

In MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(2.465, 1);
+-------------------+
| TRUNCATE(2.465,1) |
+-------------------+
|               2.4 | 
+-------------------+
```

I only know of HiveQL's `ROUND()`, however, I do not want any rounding to occur.

Reference: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-truncate-function.php

Comment: you could try to play with `split` or `substring_index`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180835/deleting-part-of-a-string-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit convoluted, but:

```
floor(2.465 * 10) / 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp_extract:

```
select regexp_extract(2.456,'\\d+\\.?\\d?',0)
```

Result:

```
2.4
```

`\\d+` means one or more digits,
`\\.?` means zero or one dot,
`\\d?` means zero or one digit

You may want to add also `-` sign at the regexp beginning: `-?`

The result is of type String. You can cast to float if necessary:

```
select cast(regexp_extract(2.456,'\\d+\\.?\\d?',0) as float)
```